# Restrict choices using two foreignkey relationships in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have three models, a household model, a household-member model, and an occupations models as described below. I would like the occupations model to only show members that belong to a particular household (which is related to field sno). How does one do something like this?

Would be grateful for any help.

```
class Household(models.Model):
    village =  models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    household_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    form_number = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    head_of_household = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)


class member(models.Model):
    sno = models.ForeignKey(Household, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    sex_choices2 = (
        ('M','Male'),
        ('F','Female'),
        )
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=sex_choices2,blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("sno", "person_number"),)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class occupations(models.Model):
    sno = models.ForeignKey(Household,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    person_number = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.ForeignKey(member, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (("sno", "person_number","occupation"),)
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. Is it like you want to choose an occupation, and only show the members and their detail household?

Comment: I have an admin form based on the household model, with tabular inlines based on member and occupations models. There are households, and then there are members of households, and some of those members have one or more occupations. When I am recording data of occupations of members of a particular household, I want the foreignkey relation to show me a drop down with only members of that household rather than all records in the members table.